# How do I apply a filter to a google datastore collection based on a key?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am trying to use the filter() method based on a key argument. For example:

```
user_id="agxkZXZ-emFiZXRhLTJyCgsSBFVzZXIYGAw"
d=datamodel.Task.all()
d.filter("user=",user_id) 
results=d.fetch(1024)
```

This produces zero results,  and its probably because the key isn't in the right format. If this where gql would I have to use the Key() function like this:

```
db.gqlQuery("select * from Task where user=Key(:1)",user_id)
```

However I don't think I can use the Key() function within a filter,  but there must be some python functional equivalent...  Is there a way to properly format a key to be used within the filter() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use `Key` instances within a filter!

```
from google.appengine.api.datastore_types import Key

user_id="agxkZXZ-emFiZXRhLTJyCgsSBFVzZXIYGAw"
datamodel.Task.all().filter('user', Key(user_id))
```

Comment: Hmm thanks,  but no dice.  That function returns the same base64 string.

Comment: `Key(user_id)` returns a `Key` object based on the string-encoded key value in `user_id`.  If you take the `str` representation of that object, it'll convert it back to the encoded string.  But it should otherwise be usable in the filter.  This assumes that you have entities of kind `Task` whose `user` property is a `Key` value equivalent to the given key.  Can you confirm that the property values are being stored this way?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the proper ``Key``? The return value of ``Key(user_id)`` should be an instance of the class ``Key``, not a string.

My answer assumes a model where ``user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)`` (which takes a ``Key`` as its value)

Comment: @tdavis,  actually its a db.ReferenceProperty(None),  but it looks like i have to make it a db.StringProperty() in order for this to work. Also I wont' be notified of your response unless you put `@rook`.